# How to import customized Android versions into Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, mobile, jar, android-studio

My problem is as follows:

I am trying to import a project from eclipse into Android Studio. The problem is that this project is built against a customized version of android 4.2.2 in order to support a tablet that was built specifically for the company. In Eclipse we had to specify the order so that the customAndroid.jar file would be compiled before the default android4.2.2 jar download by SDK Manager. How can we do the same in Android Studio utilizing Gradle?

I have tried placing the customizedAndroid.jar with in the app/lib folder and specifying that it is a library dependency.Also made sure that the jar was listed under dependencies in build.gradle.

In eclipes under project properties ~> Java Build Path we specify that the 
customAndroid.jar should be built first. it is as follows

1. customAndroid.jar
2. Default Android Library Android (4.2.2)
3. Some more custom libraries
4. Application/src folder
5. Application/gen folder

How can I achieve this type of build with Android Studio and Gradle, or is this currently  not supported by Android Studio?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might poke around with how Amazon has you develop for the Fire Phone, as it too requires a custom `compileSdkVersion`: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/configuring-your-app-for-fire-phone

Comment: Can you kindly explain to me what the syntax of this line is doing by gradle. compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17". I understand that it is setting the sdk version for the compiler. I just don't understand where it is looking for it the "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17" How does Gradle know where this is located? Where is this pointing to?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know, and I don't have it installed. What I'd do is install it, then go poking around my SDK to see if I can find a match. I can tell you that, in Gradle, colons are sometimes used as path separators. I'd check the `add-ons/` and `extras/` directories of your SDK, plus `platforms/` (which is where stuff like `android-19` and `android-L` come from as `compileSdkVersion` values).